# What does it mean when not only the main method is executed (Java)?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics, jcomponent

I created a class called StickFigure that extends JComponents and draws a stick figure using `paintComponent()`. On another class, `StickFigureRunner`, there is a main method that calls for a frame and a panel, a new StickFigure is added to the frame and the frame prints the stick figure. The part that confuses me is the part where the stick figure is drawn, even though there is no method calling for paintComponent in the main method. Why does it happen?

Here is the StickFigure class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * A new kind of component that displays a stick figure
 * 
 * @author Ilai Tamari
 */

public class StickFigure extends JComponent
{
    /**
     * Constructor for StickFigure, that extends the constructor of JComponent and
     * also sets the preferred size.
     */
    public StickFigure()
    {
        super();

        // Specify the preferred size for this component
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 270));
    }

    /**
     * This method paints the StickFigure on the frame
     * 
     * @param g The Graphics which is used to draw the figure
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // paint the head
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(60, 0, 60, 60);
        
        // paint the shirt
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 60, 180, 30);
        g.fillRect(60, 60, 60, 90);

        // paint the pants
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(60, 150, 60, 120);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(90, 180, 90, 270);
    }
}
```

Here is the StickFigureRunner class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Create a StickFigure and display it in a frame.
 * 
 * @author Ilai Tamari
 *
 */

public class StickFigureRunner
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declare the objects to show
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contents = new JPanel();
        StickFigure stickFig = new StickFigure();

        // set up the contents
        contents.add(stickFig);

        // display the contents in a frame
        frame.setContentPane(contents);
        frame.setTitle("Stick Figure");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(250, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: When you create a `JFrame` and invoke `setVisible`, the frame will be drawn by calling its `paintComponent` method. This will lead to all contents of the frame being drawn aswell. In your case, the frame being drawn will lead to the `JPanel` and therefore the `StickFigure` to be drawn, as these are the contents of your frame. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @maloomeister *"the frame will be drawn by calling its `paintComponent` method"* ITYM *"the frame will be drawn by calling its `paint` method"*. Otherwise, good info.

Comment: This is how oop is supposed to work. If you look at the Swing code that is executing behind your back, the components only draw themselves, they don't draw their children. They set things up, then the component asks each of their children to draw themselves. Your StickFigure fits into that hierarchy.